# Laravel 4 : How to return an array of elements instead of array of objects from Eloquent?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

Right now, I'm doing this :

```
  $raw_messages_id = Messages::select('id')->get();
  $messages_id = array();
  foreach($raw_messages_id as $message_id){
       array_push($messages_id,$message_id->id);
  }
```

In order to get this :

```
[1034,2031,1023,2234,...]
```

Is there a better approach to this? I want to prevent the use of looping server-side because it takes a lot of time.

---

**What I have tried**

```
$raw_messages_id = Messages::select('id')->get()->toArray();
```

OR

```
$raw_messages_id = Messages::select('id')->get(array('id'))->toArray();
```

**unwanted result**

```
[{id:1034},{id:2031},{id:1023},...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
$ids = Messages::lists('id');
```